# Allowe location services again programmatically

Tags: iphone, safari, location

I have disabled location services on Safari (iphone) when I load my web clicking on "Not allow". How can I allow it again for the same web page (programmatically)

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change user preferences programmatically. You can simply check if location services are on and your application has access to services if not prompt user to allow location services to use this feature in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you will have to go in to the settings app and enable it there.

Answer (score 1):

(if you want your app on Appstore) Programmatically you can not call that dialog which asks you for location services permission.

manually go to **Settings** -> **General**, scroll to the bottom and go to **Reset**-> **Reset Location & Privacy**.